# How to update the details dynamically in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**User.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <label>Val:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="val" name="val" v-model="item.val" /><br />
      <label>kk:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="kk" name="kk" v-model="item.kk" /><br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" @click="updatedata" />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "User",
  data: function () {
    return {
      val: "",
      kk: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updatedata() {
      val: this.item.val,
      kk: this.item.kk,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Helloworld.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b>Vuejs dynamic routing</b>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <b>{{ item.id }}.</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'UserWithID', params: { id: item.id } }">
        {{ item.kk }}
      </router-link>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />

    {{ $route.params.id }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import User from "./User.vue";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { id: 1, val: "1", kk: "mm" },
        { id: 2, val: "22", kk: "aa" },
        { id: 3, val: "55", kk: "dd" },
        { id: 4, val: "77", kk: "gg" },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

I am trying to update data in vuejs, I have given routing and able to make it dynamic. But when trying to update the data. How to give reference to the component and update the data. i have taken click event where onclick of that button. I should able to update the data.
I am trying to update data in vuejs, I have given routing and able to make it dynamic. But when trying to update the data. How to give reference to the component and update the data. i have taken click event where onclick of that button. I should able to update the data.

Comment: I use vuex for that

Comment: @MikkiUkraine  If possible, can u please give some example for above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your components is a separate Vue instance.
That means you can't access the same `items` object using `this.items` in the `User` or `HelloWorld` components.

What you need to do is "raise up the state" so that both components can access the same `items` object.
You can either do this using a mutual parent component and props or by using a store like vuex.
Documentation for props: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html
Documentation for vuex: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

I've modified your codesandbox using props:
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-gauss-62tqm

---

In a couple of words:

- Display the values (`items`) passed from the parent component (or vuex) and use it as the "source of truth".
- Emit/dispatch an event (e.g. `update`) passing the new data to the component.
- Update the data in the parent component/store.

Comment: Thanks.So, after user enter details and click on button Now in the console the updated array is printing. .  But what if I want to redirect that Hello world page. Show details there. I used like this.$route.push("Helloworld") but it's not redirecting.

Comment: It's `this.$router`, not `this.$route` - maybe try that?